# Why is my input not displayed as in the documentation?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, slds

Here is my code where `onclick` is added:

```
                          <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Enter city</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right">
                              <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
                              </svg>
                              <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder text…" class="slds-input" />
                              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Clear" onclick={handleChange}>
                                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-icon-text-light" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#clear"></use>
                                </svg>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Clear</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

[image]

Here is the code from the documentation:
[click](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Icon-and-clear-button)

Why is there no search and clean logo and why does `onclick` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Copying code from the SLDS blueprints do not translate to working components, they are more like guidelines.

the searhc icon does not display because the asset folder does not exist in your SF org, instead use (replace assets with _slds):

```
 <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
      <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
 </svg>
```

as per your onclick not working, not sure what you are expecting it to do? where is your js controller?

Blueprints are note meant to work ootb.